# Подтверждение, что я не робот, зачем?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение, recaptcha

За последние несколько дней я ответил на 2 вопроса. В обоих случаях, после нажатия кнопки отправить у меня вылезло окно подтверждения, что я не робот.
При этом я его не сразу заметил, нажал "ответить" и перешел на другую вкладку.

Кажется, что эта проверка излишняя. Возможно ее можно как то убрать?

**PS**
Даже если я робот, но мои ответы хорошие(рейтинг больше 100 например), то наверное такие ответы все равно стоит принимать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96099/discussion-on-question-by-viktorov------).

Comment: Вы про проверку с помощью ввода кода с табло или выбора картинок с такими-то предметами?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Тема поднималась на meta.stackexchange.com:

- [Why is Captcha for higher rep users even necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3346)

  В 2009-м году Этвуд писал, что для людей с 10К+ репутации порог появления капчи выше.
- [Are captchas necessary for established users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143463)

  В 2012-м просили отменить проверку для пользователей с высокой репутацией. Ответа не последовало.

**P.S.** Так Вы прошли проверку или нет? Крайне подозрительно что в вопросе этот момент старательно обошли стороной.

Comment: Не сразу. Я сначала ее не заметил, и мой ответ просто не публиковался некоторое время. Похоже, что я частично робот

Answer (score 5):

> И по прежнему, мне кажется, что рейтинг - достаточный показатель
>   качества ответов. А сделаны ответы ботом или нет, уже не важно.

А потом вашу учётку с хорошей репой уведёт спамер и ботом создаст 1000 ответов с рекламой прежде, чем модераторы успеют среагировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сдается мне, что спамер нацелившийся на SO сможет и ботом капчу обойти.

Comment: Читал недавно статью про капчу а именно про гугловский сервис ReCaptcha и могу сказать, что параметров поведения во время прохождения капчи учитывается много, вплоть до движения курсора, так что без нейронки её почти невозможно обойти